# Keyboard Shortcuts have stopped working since version 50 of Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Since version Chrome version 50 was released it seems that keyboard shortcuts for extensions have stopped working.

The user had created the extension which connects to a 3rd party App which has stopped working correctly since moving to version 50. He is running version 51.0.2704.63.

For this we have reached out Google Product Team and they told us that :
"Currently we do not support app or extension development however I have looked into your issue further. I found the following Page https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands which seems to indicate that keyboard shortcut support has been available since Chrome version 25 and does not appear to have been discontinued. I would advise having your user ensure that his extension has the same formula that is listed on that page ".

So now as it is not supported by Google core Apps Support. Can anyone advise or provide directions for this issue would be helpful for us to proceed.

Thanks,
Vipul

Comment: Please share your keyboard shortcut implementation and error logs too. Have you also tried going through the given [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands)?

Comment: I have checked the manifest.json and could see that the permission given looks like:
"permissions": [ "storage", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "tabs" ],

So it seems that the code has cross-origin permissions in the extensions manifest file.